# Determining an equation for the current after the switches close

Tags: capacitor, inductor

I know that the solution of of the form `i(t) = A*sin(wt + phi)`, I am really confused where to start in finding A, w and phi however. Here is the circuit in question:

[image]

The switches close at time `t=0`

Comment: Assuming infinite time before the switch switches, that means it starts in steady state. Since it is a DC source, what is a cap and inductor at DC? Also "switch closes" doesn't mean much for DPST switches.

Comment: so the caps are open circuits and the inductors are short circuits, so the initial current as they close will be `5 / (200 + 200)A`, and since the current cant change instantly because there will be an infinite voltage then as they close it will stay the same, that's pretty all I'm pretty sure i have done correctly

Comment: Il(0-) must be 0.0125A and Vc(0-) should be 5V due to how they behave in a DC circuit iirc.

Comment: oh my bad yeah that was a typo

Comment: Now that you have initial conditions, you need a differential equation of the circuit after it switches. Or you can use shortcuts since you know the form of the solution.

Comment: \$di/dt = A\omega cos(\cdot)\$. For this circuit, after switches change over, \$L di_L(t=0+)/dt = v_C(t=0+)\$. So, you can solve for A and \$\phi\$ from two equations and two unknowns. \$\omega\$ is the standard formula for LC circuits for this circuit also.

Comment: I am pretty sure the one i found was incorrect, but here it is https://www.symbolab.com/solver/vector-cross-product-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bd%5E%7B2%7Di%7D%7Bdt%5E%7B2%7D%7D-%5Cfrac%7Bi%7D%7BLC%7D%3D0, im not sure how do do the fancy math markup stuff

Comment: In short, there are three unknowns. We need three equations. Two of them are \$i_L(0+)=\dots\$ and \$L\cdot di_L(0+)/dt= v_C(0+)=\dots\$. You need one more equation.

Comment: kk thnx for the help, ill see if i can calculate it now.

Comment: is `i(t) = -0.125Sin(10000t - 5.74(degrees))` correct?

Comment: You can use Falstead simulator to verify. Note you never gave us LC either. Warning: don't use degrees inside sine, especially if there is more than one term in there since the units of 10000t must match up with degrees and it gets all weird and nonstandard. Stick with radians.

Answer (score 1):

The initial conditions are \$\small v_C=2.5\:V\$ and \$\small i_L=\frac{5}{400}=12.5\:mA\$.

For \$\small t \ge 0\$, the same current, \$\small i\$, flows through \$\small L\$ and \$\small C\$. If this current is assumed to flow clockwise, KVL gives

$$\small 2.5-\frac{1}{C}\int i\:dt =L\frac{di}{dt}$$

Differentiating and rearranging gives the 2nd order ODE

$$\small \frac{d^2 i}{dt^2}+\frac{i}{LC}=0 $$

Solution is of the form \$\small i=Asin(\omega t+\phi)\$.

Substituting for \$\small i\$ in the ODE

$$\small -A\omega ^2 sin(\omega t+\phi)+\frac{Asin(\omega t+\phi)}{LC}=0$$

Hence \$\small \omega^2 =\frac{1}{LC}\$

Since the \$\small LC\$ circuit is has no resistance, the phase angle between current and voltage is known, hence the value of \$\small A\$ can be found from the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course). Besides that the answer of [@Chu](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/66771/chu) is excellent.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjms9T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_1\$ and \$\text{I}_3\$:

- $$\text{V}_1=\frac{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag4$$
- $$\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code to find \$(4)\$ and \$(5)\$:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, 
   I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I3 == V2/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> ((R2 + R3 + R4) Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I2 -> ((R3 + R4) Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I3 -> (R2 Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V1 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V2 -> (R2 R4 Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4))}}
```

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lower case letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag6$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\text{sL}\tag7$$
- The input voltage is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\tag8$$

So, we get for \$(4)\$ and \$(5)\$:

- $$\text{v}_1\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_3+\text{sL}\right)\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_3+\text{sL}\right)+\text{R}_1\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_3+\text{sL}\right)}\tag9$$
- $$\text{i}_3\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_3+\text{sL}\right)+\text{R}_1\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_3+\text{sL}\right)}\tag{10}$$

Now, when we use inverse Laplace transform we can see:

- $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{V}_1\left(t\right)=\frac{\text{R}_3\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3}\tag{11}$$
- $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{I}_3\left(t\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3}\tag{12}$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-codes to find \$(11)\$ and \$(12)\$:

```
In[2]:=R2 = 1/(s*c);
R4 = s*L;
Vi = u/s; FullSimplify[
 Limit[InverseLaplaceTransform[(R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), s, t], t -> Infinity, 
  Assumptions -> c > 0 && L > 0 && u > 0 && R1 > 0 && R3 > 0]]

Out[2]=ConditionalExpression[(R3 u)/(R1 + R3), 
 1/Sqrt[-4 c L R1 (R1 + R3) + (L + c R1 R3)^2] \[Element] Reals && 
  Sqrt[-4 c L R1 (R1 + R3) + (L + c R1 R3)^2] > 0 && 
  Sqrt[-4 c L R1 (R1 + R3) + (L + c R1 R3)^2] < L + c R1 R3 && 
  L + c R1 R3 + Sqrt[-4 c L R1 (R1 + R3) + (L + c R1 R3)^2] > 0]

In[3]:=R2 = 1/(s*c);
R4 = s*L;
Vi = u/s; FullSimplify[
 Limit[InverseLaplaceTransform[(R2 Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), s, t], t -> Infinity, 
  Assumptions -> c > 0 && L > 0 && u > 0 && R1 > 0 && R3 > 0]]

Out[3]=ConditionalExpression[u/(R1 + R3), 
 1/Sqrt[-4 c L R1 (R1 + R3) + (L + c R1 R3)^2] \[Element] Reals && 
  Sqrt[-4 c L R1 (R1 + R3) + (L + c R1 R3)^2] > 0 && 
  Sqrt[-4 c L R1 (R1 + R3) + (L + c R1 R3)^2] < L + c R1 R3 && 
  L + c R1 R3 + Sqrt[-4 c L R1 (R1 + R3) + (L + c R1 R3)^2] > 0]
```

Now, when the switch closes we can use [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) to write:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=-\text{V}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\tag{13}$$

Now, we know the voltage current relations:

- [Capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Current%E2%80%93voltage_relation):
  $$\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_\text{C}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}\tag{14}$$
- [Inductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor#Constitutive_equation):
  $$\text{V}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{L}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\tag{15}$$

And the circuit is in series so \$\text{I}\left(t\right):=\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\$. And we know the initial conditons:

- $$\text{I}\left(0\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3}\tag{16}$$
- $$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right)=\frac{\text{R}_3\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3}=-\text{I}'\left(0\right)\cdot\text{L}\tag{17}$$

So, we can solve for the current:

$$\text{I}\left(t\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\sqrt{\text{L}}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\text{L}}\cos\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\text{CL}}}\right)-\text{R}_3\sqrt{\text{C}}\sin\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\text{CL}}}\right)}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3}\tag{18}$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code to find \$(18)\$:

```
In[4]:=DSolve[{x''[t]*L + (1/c)*x[t] == 0, 
  x[0] == u/(R1 + R3), (R3 u)/(R1 + R3) == -x'[0]*L}, x[t], t]

Out[4]={{x[t] -> -((
    u (-Sqrt[L] Cos[t/(Sqrt[c] Sqrt[L])] + 
       Sqrt[c] R3 Sin[t/(Sqrt[c] Sqrt[L])]))/(Sqrt[L] (R1 + R3)))}}
```